# Running Silverstripe with MAMP and Gulp

Tags: gulp, mamp, silverstripe

I'm trying to set up a local dev environment for a Silverstripe build which was set up by someone else. I'm not all that familiar with Silverstripe so am a bit lost as to how to do this. I can't share much of the code for security reasons but I can see that gulp is used for watching the local changes. Happy to provide what ever else is needed to get this going just cant provide specifics obviously.

Here is what I've done so far:

- installed MAMP
- cloned Repo to the htdocs folder within MAMP
- run composer install in the root and npm install in the theme directory
- turned on the MAMP server - am redirected to localhost:8888
- have gone to the localhost:8888/repo and am shown the error - cannot find index.php
- When I run gulp the browser opens a localhost:3000 page but it never completes loading, rather it hangs.

I understand the index.php error but the previous dev had this running with the current set up so I am hoping to not move anything around just yet. There is a 'public' folder with an index.php file in it if there is a way I can tell the server to look here for it.

composer.json Contents:

```
    {
"name": "silverstripe/installer",
"type": "silverstripe-recipe",
"description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "silverstripe/recipe-plugin": "^1.2",
    "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "4.2.1@stable",
    "silverstripe-themes/simple": "~3.2.0",
    "loeken/cryptocompare-api-php-wrapper": "dev-master",
    "zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php": "^2.2",
    "intercom/intercom-php": "^3.2",
    "tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent": "^4",
    "silverstripe/googlesitemaps": "dev-master",
    "ryanpotter/silverstripe-cms-theme": "^3.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
    "deployer/deployer": "^6.2",
    "lekoala/silverstripe-debugbar": "^2.0"
},
"extra": {
    "project-files-installed": [
        "app/.htaccess",
        "app/_config.php",
        "app/_config/mysite.yml",
        "app/src/Page.php",
        "app/src/PageController.php"
    ],
    "public-files-installed": [
        ".htaccess",
        "index.php",
        "install-frameworkmissing.html",
        "install.php",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 600
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev"
    }
```

Any suggestions of what to try next would be greatly appreciated. Nothing I can find online seems to mention using gulp and MAMP in tandem - unsure If I'm just understand their purpose incorrectly.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I need '50 reputation' to comment so I will instead reply as an answer.

It sounds like you are using SilverStripe version `^4.1`, since you got the 'public' folder.

Do the following:

1. Make sure you got a `.htaccess` file in the root (outside public folder) which redirects all requests to the public folder:

   `(root .htaccess)`
      `RewriteEngine On`
      `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1`
2. Run `composer vendor-expose` in the root to expose all files which should be accessed by the visitors, (custom css, js, images etc...). The files & folders that gets exposed are specified in the `composer.json` file under `"expose": [...]`. The files gets copied over to the `public` folder

Comment: Hey @Conny Nyman, Thanks for that, I have checked and there is a .htaccess file and its contents reflect the above. I ran composer vendor-expose which seemed to run successfully. My composer json is slightly different though, I have added it above so you can see what I mean. Also could you advise me what order to run things in, for example do I run gulp and then turn on the MAMP server or the other way around? Still being hit by the same error on the index.php file not being found. Cheers, Tim

Comment: Hmm you have no 'expose' object specified in the composer file. Perhaps Gulp is taking care of that in your project? I assume you use gulp to compile and compress js, scss files etc.. into a folder in 'public/resources...' and maybe watch for file changes in src files? 
It is difficult to say in what order you should run things, since we do not know what e.g. Gulp do in your case. You should look in the gulpfile.js file and see  what Gulp is configured to do.

Comment: I suggest you create a new folder and install a fresh SS project with composer. Then you are able to compare file permissions,  .htaccess files etc.. which could help you to find the issue. And in worst case if nothing works, try to copy the custom code part over to the fresh installation and continue from there.
Guide on how to install a fresh ss project with composer:

1) open a cmd & make a new folder
2) cd into your new folder
3) run `composer create-project silverstripe/installer . ^4` 
(or even better if you install the exact SS version you got in the other project e.g. 4.2)

Comment: Hey @Conny, I managed to get something showing up by telling mamp to load from the public folder under preferences - Can now see the page.ss template (which has the custom header and footer but no content from the other pages) - progress but not quite there! Thanks for you suggestions, I'll check back in if I figure it out!

Comment: @TimTolley Okay, nice that it is going forward! Hmm you say you don't see any content from other pages, have you configured the `.env` file in the root to point to the correct database with username&password? And also uploaded a copy of the SQL Dump(db)? The .env file is probably ignored in the repo but is necessary in order for SilverStripe to connect to the database. Also remember to run `dev/build?flush=all` in the browser when setting up a new project.

Comment: I really appreciate this, the dev who was working on this before was completely unwilling to help me out so I'd be stuck without this! So I have the .env file configured (I have the one from the laptop which he was running locally on) which is different to the one on the deployment (AWS plesk) so I assume this is set up for a dev DB. IE. DB password is root and DB server is localhost. So I think thats correct. The thing is though, the home page I was expecting to load is completely hard coded in a HomePage.ss file which is within the folder structure = theme - templates - StaticPages

Comment: Its as though the routes arent running properly.. Under the - theme - templates folder there is a Page.ss file which is what is currently loading on the MAMP localhost. Do I need to configure something to run the static pages on a local env?

Comment: In SilverStripe you have outer & inner layout templates. SilverStripe will use the corresponding template for the current active `PageType`. In order to find out what `PageType` the home page is you need to login to the `Admin` section `baseUrl/admin`, after logging in go to the `Pages` section. Then go through the root pages and look for one with the `URL Segment` set to `.../home`. The page with url `/home` will work as the home page.

Comment: When you find this page go to `Settings tab`, there you will see `Page type`. If this is e.g. HomePage, then SilverStripe will look for a template called `HomePage.ss` in both `/templates` (outer layout) & `/templates/Layout` (inner layout) folder. If SS does not find `HomePage.ss` it will fallback and use `Page.ss`. This `https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/tutorials/building_a_basic_site/` guide is for SS 3 but it works the same in SS 4 regarding PageTypes & templates, I recommend you read it in order to understand what templates will be used when.

Comment: Also, did you start off with an empty DB or did you import a SQL dump of the production DB? If empty, you will not have any `Pages` in the pages section except for the default pages created by SilverStripe. And that would explain a lot why only Page.ss template is used because it will not use any other templates because you have no custom pages that require them :)